# When are the files in ~.vim/after/ loaded?

Tags: vimrc, startup

I have some shortcuts for `LaTeX` in `./vim/after/latex.vim` but when I open a `LaTeX` file, this shortcuts are not available, and I need to load the file manually. I guess this is related to the `Latex-vim` plugin.

How can I set these shortcuts to be loaded automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add them into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex/`.

`:h 'rtp'` IIRC and `:h ftplugin`

Comment: Can I throw stuff in whatever ``<filename>.vim`` in that folder?

Comment: Yes. That's the idea. Anything in that directory will be loaded once per buffer of (La)Tex filetype you open, and after the equivalent (ft)plugins you've installed -- I'm simplifying what's happening, but that's the idea. Read the doc for more explanations.